# package-lock.json package requirement vulnerability (npm)

Tags: node.js, npm

So, I have this package, inside the package-lock.json:

```
"micromatch": {
  "version": "2.3.11",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/micromatch/-/micromatch-2.3.11.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-hmd8l9FyCzY0MdBNDRUpO9OMFWU=",
  "requires": {
    "arr-diff": "^2.0.0",
    "array-unique": "^0.2.1",
    "braces": "^1.8.2",
    "expand-brackets": "^0.1.4",
    "extglob": "^0.3.1",
    "filename-regex": "^2.0.0",
    "is-extglob": "^1.0.0",
    "is-glob": "^2.0.1",
    "kind-of": "^3.0.2",
    "normalize-path": "^2.0.1",
    "object.omit": "^2.0.0",
    "parse-glob": "^3.0.4",
    "regex-cache": "^0.4.2"
  }
}
```

The vulnerability is: "braces": "^1.8.2", when I run npm audit, it says that its fixed at 2.3.1, but I can't seem to update it, or just don't know how.

**Things I tried:**

- npm install both micromatch and braces, then doing npm audit fix.
- npm install && npm uninstall both micromatch and braces, and then running  npm update
- deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and doing an npm i -f
- editing package-lock.json manually, changing the version and the requirement to a dependency and then doing an npm audit fix (which it fixed it, but then I ran npm install, and it rolled back the version to 1.8.2)

There are probably a couple of things I don't understand from npm dependencies. So how can I fix this?

Edited for package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "micromatch": "^3.1.10",
    "prop-types": "latest",
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-async-component": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.2",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.5",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.54"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try `npm audit fix --force` ??

Comment: I did, and it did not solve the problem. It says that I need to manually resolve the vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your micromatch module to the latest version 3.1, the vulnerability comes because micromatch 2.3.11 that you are using, uses older version of braces. The braces version is upgraded in the latest release for micromatch so simply upgrade your micromatch module. That would resolve your issue.

To upgrade,

1. replace your micromatch version in your main package.json to 3.1.10 and save
   it.
2. Delete the package-lock.json file
3. do npm i

See this commit when micromatch upgraded the braces module - https://github.com/micromatch/micromatch/commit/cdff648d3f50f2f6342c7f23c899f95d8244b144

Comment: How do I upgrade it? In my post says that I already tried installing it, and then doing and npm audit fix and did not fixed the problem, since the package-lock.json wont update the version from the requirement, even tho I have a newer version installed in the package.json.
And also my post very clearly states that "I can't seem to update it, or just don't know how", so answering "You need to upgrade it" without really explaining the process is not actually helpful.

Comment: I just did that, but the same old version of micromatch, with the vulnerabilities, keeps appearing in the package-lock.json.

Comment: Can you post your package.json file?

Comment: I edited the main post.
Edit: Micromatch is only in the package.json because the solution we just tried, but I don't need it there for the project to work, and if possible, don't want it there.

Comment: As you say you don't want to include micromatch in package.json but if you are using the module in your codebase then you will need to commit the files for micromatch as well. This is something I would not recommend to do, instead you should include it in package.json

Also, I tried npm install with the contents of your package.json and it works fine for me. See the screenshot here https://imgur.com/a/pmj0VsL

Comment: I'm not directly using it, it is a dependency for another package, I think react-scripts uses it.
How did you make it work? Maybe I need to create a new react project? Because it definitely doesn't work for me.

Comment: I just pasted that to a fresh package.json file and performed npm install. Maybe you can also try npm run eject to see if react scripts uses the older version though I don’t think there’s something wrong with react scripts

Comment: Doing an npm run eject, then npm audit fix --force solved the issue, 2 packages where out of date, babel-jest and jest. Now how do I reverse this operation, as I didn't really wanted to eject.

Comment: Aah unfortunately you cannot reverse npm eject

Comment: I just realized that when I create a new react app with my current environment already has the same exact error in it. Maybe because I'm using the LTS version of node.js?